# How to pass URL from jQuery dialog to CKEditor dialog

Tags: jquery, ajax, dialog, popup, ckeditor

**I am trying to pass a URL from a *jQuery dialog* back to a *CKEditor dialog***.

Both CKEditor and jQuery dialogs work.

<strike>The problem is that I don't know how to pass CKEditorFuncNum to the server.</strike> *I dived into the source code and searched for 'CKEditorFuncNum' and found a way to access this variable.*

Now I get the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getDialog' of undefined
```

**This is the workflow:**

- call CKEditor dialog [OK]
- call jQuery function that makes an ajax request [OK]
- call jQuery dialog with the content of the ajax request [OK]
- close jQuery dialog and pass url back to CKEditor dialog (URL field) **<- here is the problem**

*I changed the browse button to call a jQuery function (jQuery Popup)*

```
...
{
   type : 'button',
   id : 'browseInternal',
   label : 'jQuery Popup',
   onClick :function() {
     var funcNum = this.getDialog().getParentEditor()._.filebrowserFn;
     showJQueryPopUp(funcNum);
   }
}
...
```

*The jQuery function makes a get request, passing the CKEditorFuncNum value. <strike>**How do I access the CKEditorFuncNum value?**</strike> (see below)*

```
function showJQueryPopUp(funcNum) {
    ajax_url = '../../../site_links?CKEditorFuncNum=' + funcNum;
    $.get(ajax_url, function(data) {
        $('#my_dialog_content').html(data);
        $('#my_dialog').dialog('open');
    });
};
```

*The ajax request returns a list of urls and some JavaScript code:*

```
<a href="#" onclick="modify_link('http://www.google.com'); return false;">
  Google
</a>
<a href="#" onclick="modify_link('http://www.yahoo.com'); return false;">
  Yahoo
</a>
<a href="#" onclick="modify_link('http://www.microsoft.com'); return false;">
  Microsoft
</a>

<script type='text/javascript'>
  function modify_link(url) {
    window.parent.CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(<%= @funcNum %>, url, '' );
  }
</script>
```

Calling *window.parent.CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(...);* results in the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getDialog' of undefined
```

**How do I resove this conflict?**

**Is the scope incorrect?**

**How do I get hold of the *CKEditor dialog*?**

**How do I fill the URL field of the CKEditor dialog with the selected url from the jQuery dialog?**

I would appreciate any advice. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here is how I solved it:

Passing values back to the dialog using `window.parent.CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction...);` did not work for me. So I looked for an other way to pass some value back to the CKEditor dialog.

I defined a callback function (`ref`) right before calling the jQuery dialog (`showJQueryPopUp()`):

```
...
{
  type : 'button',
  id : 'browseInternal',
  label : 'jQuery Popup',
  onClick :function() {
      var dialog = this.getDialog();
      var selected_url = dialog.getContentElement('info', 'url').getValue();

      var ref = CKEDITOR.tools.addFunction(
          function(url)
          {
              dialog.getContentElement('info','url').setValue(url);
          });

      var funcNum = this.getDialog().getParentEditor()._.filebrowserFn;
      var editor_name = this.getDialog().getParentEditor().name;
      showJQueryPopUp(funcNum, editor_name, ref, selected_url);
  }
}
...
```

I make an ajax request passing `funcNum`, `ref`, and `selected_url`. (`ref` is just a number)

```
function showJQueryPopUp(funcNum, editor_name, ref, selected_url) {
    var ajax_url = '../../../site_links?CKEditorFuncNum=' + funcNum + '&ref=' + ref + '&selected_url=' + selected_url;
    $.get(ajax_url, function(data) {
        $('#my_dialog_content').html(data);
        $('#my_dialog').dialog('open');
    });
};
```

The serverside script extracts the parameters and passes it to the view (@ref):

```
<a href="#" onclick="modify_link('http://www.google.com'); return false;">
  Google
</a>
<a href="#" onclick="modify_link('http://www.yahoo.com'); return false;">
  Yahoo
</a>
<a href="#" onclick="modify_link('http://www.microsoft.com'); return false;">
  Microsoft
</a>
<script type='text/javascript'>
  function modify_link(url) {
    CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(<%= @ref %>, url);
  }
```